# Are there other practical/commercial uses of Ruby other than Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

Are there other practical/commercial uses of Ruby other than Rails and other web development frameworks?

I would like to know what other applications is Ruby applied to, as a general purpose programming language.

Comment: Data transformation; code generation; rapid prototyping; documentation generation: these are all things I personally use it for. However, this question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, just check the [Success Stories](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/success-stories/) section of its webpage

Answer (score 2):

It is my personal choice for the sys-admin scripts I have to write. I manage the scheduling for the super-cluster here at Vanderbilt, and we have some 500 linux compute nodes that have to be kept in synch. The perl scripts of my predecessor are nearly unreadable, which says more about perl that about his scripting abilities. Ruby is far more readable, hence maintainable, and the other staff easily modify what I write for their own purposes. So, sys-admin work is the better for ruby.

Answer (score 1):

C# is my bread and butter, but any general purpose scripting or automation I do in Ruby now days.

Recently I wrote an archive generator for Oracle that takes in a list of table names, interrogates the data dictionary and outputs archive table definitions and triggers to write write to them. It's a couple of hundred lines of Ruby that can generate thousands of lines of DDL.

I really like the Ruby as play doh analogy in [this](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2008/11/9/legos-play-doh-and-programming) post. It's very true.

Then there's [Albacore](https://github.com/derickbailey/Albacore/wiki/Getting-Started). This is a perfect scenario for Ruby - you can super productively script build tasks instead of having to deal with the nightmare of large XML configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

http://accidentaltechnologist.com/ruby/10-alternative-ruby-web-frameworks/

Comment: The OP is not asking for other web frameworks, s/he is asking what Ruby is good for _besides_ web programming.

Comment: Oops, didn´t read the question carefully.

Comment: @Phrogz what do you mean by "The OP"?

Comment: @rb512 The abbreviation "OP" means "original poster"; I was simply clarifying what hsgubert was asking for.

Comment: got it, was just curious about your abbreviation